# Character whose ASCII value is equal to tick the mark on YouTube and Instagram

Tags: unicode, youtube, instagram

How can we add verified *tick mark* on social media platforms using only Unicode? Is there a character which has a very high resemblance to it?

**YouTube Verified Image**

[image]

**Instagram Verified Image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ☑️ or ✅ looks like those. Twitter even [has a list of emojis that look like the verified symbol](https://blog.emojipedia.org/why-you-cant-use-these-emojis-in-your-twitter-name/) (and prevents those emojis from being used in usernames).

Answer (score -1):

The "blue tick" or verified badge on Instagram cannot be generated using keyboard shortcuts like Alt + a specific number. The verified badge is a special status given by Instagram to verified accounts of public figures, celebrities, and global brands. It is not possible to create this badge through keyboard shortcuts or other means as it is a feature strictly controlled by Instagram for authentication and identification of certain accounts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy